# Changing prop of component in vue.js with composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

How can I change the prop value of a component and notify these components about the change?

**Parent.vue**

```
<script setup>
import Child from './Child.vue'

const finished = ref(false)

function submit() {
    finished.value = true;
}
</script>

<template>
    <Child :open="finished">
    <button @click="submit">Klick</button>
</template>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
    <div v-if="open">Dies ist ein Test.</div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['open'])

const open = ref(props.open)
</script>
```

When I click on the button, the value changes, but the child component is not notified about it. `console.log(open)` is still `false`.

I am using Vue.js version 3 with the composition API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to assign with `ref`, you can use just `props.open` in **Child.vue**.

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="props.open">Dies ist ein Test.</div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['open'])
</script>
```

However, if you want to compute this prop, you can use `computed` as the first answer from [Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim).

Comment: That was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's some conflict in the Child component, you've a prop named `open` and a ref property with the same name, which in this case give the priority to the ref  one, rename the other property to `isOpen` and define it as computed :

```html
<template>
    <div v-if="isOpen">Dies ist ein Test.</div>
</template>
  
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['open'])

const isOpen =  computed(()=>props.open)
</script>
```

[DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp1Ub1ugzAQfhXLC0Rq7J2SqFW7dWiHbnUHAkfjFGzLZ9MB8e49Q0BKpTJxvu/uvp+RPzonhgi84CXWXrvAEEJ0R2V076wP7Omsu4a13vYsE3Ku0kC2AUbmoWXTFbK0amswsFYbjWdo2CFB8rbqEHbKKNNGUwdtDcN46nXId2xUhtG3Toih6iLQXPAR7pWZlCnlwo+YURGgd10VgKo0Vy4sC+vAHBRf1yguV8AphkAHH+pO198EWS4rfnxJD6Vc+oQu5bab3/FF476vnLigNWTTzFRdG6h4sXJXnLSnWvFzCA4LKbGtk1cXFNZ/SfoTPpqgexCA/f7k7Q+Cp8WKpxUkcqKTm8Upk786Gz2wYa9bUqDxldSSgmcNyDT5Ddqwd8AgSkm4Wy0za/NPxiOrbe9ioKhuc1yTdN46pDgaIGvhLVX5R5bczj7nRBfYQolw27483x2O87RIaMJuOfLpF5343dA=)